# Get all fields from a laravel Model by name

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending a request with the name of a Model (Example: 'Client') and I need to get all fields from that  model as an array.

I have been trying to achieve this through `\ReflectionClass($request->model)` but that requires the Namespace as well, which doesn't work since the models are scattered around in the folders. Is there any way to achieve this with only the name of the model?

Comment: the model doesn't know the fields, you would have to query the table to get the fields and classes are named by their FQCN which includes their namespace .. so `Client` would mean `Client` in the root namespace so unless you created some mapping then no you won't have a way to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields of the model are built dynamically.
However you can use to get db fields

```
Schema::getColumnListing ('table_name')
```

see: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_getColumnListing

Comment: What about accessors on the model? That is, fields that are not in the database.

Comment: The correct class for that method is `Schema::getColumnListing ('table_name')`